# How to add schedule to calendar #Android

Tags: android, calendar

I want to create new schedule programmatically.I parsed title,
place and description as parameter.Date and time are calculated as fix value.Here is my code to add schedule to calendar..

```
public Uri addScheduleToCalender(String title,String place,String description) {

    long calID = 3;
    long startMillis = 0;
    long endMillis = 0;
    Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    beginTime.set(2016, 7, 22, 17, 30);
    startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
    Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    endTime.set(2016, 7, 22, 18, 45);
    endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, place);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endMillis);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, title);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, description);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "UTC/GMT +2:00");
    Uri uri;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8) {
        uri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
    } else {
        uri = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");
    }
    Uri l_uri = MainActivity.this.getContentResolver()
            .insert(uri, values);

    return l_uri;

}
```

but it doesn't work.it doesn't save any schedule data.

Comment: Have you got calendar permission ?

Comment: @madhankumar yes,I already added permission like this..                                            
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />

Comment: use `ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();` and  `Uri l_uri = cr.insert(uri, values);`

Comment: already used it.But result did't change.

Answer (score 0):

For inserting schedule task in default calendar you should use below code ,

```
// You need to pass application context as ctx parameter
ContentResolver cr = ctx.getContentResolver();

// Now add schedule as below
Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public Uri addScheduleToCalender(String title,String place,String description) {

    long calID = 3;
    long startMillis = 0;
    long endMillis = 0;
    Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    beginTime.set(2016, 07, 22, 17, 30);
    startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
    Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    endTime.set(2016, 07, 22, 18, 45);
    endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, place);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endMillis);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, title);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, description);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "UTC/GMT +2:00");
    Uri uri;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8) {
        uri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
    } else {
        uri = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");
    }
    Uri l_uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);

    return l_uri;

}
```